# Class as decorators and scope of a function over the element in the class, in python

Tags: python-3.x, class, python-decorators

When using a class decorator over a function, how can a function access self._count element inside the class. I understand that the decorators takes a callable and returns a callable. But can a function have scope to an inner element of a class decorator?

```
class decorate_class:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self._func = f
        self._count = 0

    def __call__(self, *args, **kargs):
        self._count += 1
        return self._func(*args, **kargs)

@decorate_class
def callname(name):
    print("Hello, {0}".format(name))
```

Now when i call the function with a parameter i am supposed to track the count of the number of calls being made. But what i don't understand is, how can callname function access self._count??

```
callname('Abhishek') # o/p --> Hello, Abhishek
callname('Ashley') # o/p --> Hello, Ashley
callname._count # o/p --> 2 ( But how can callname access _count?)
```

Can someone help me understand this? The scopes in particular.

Comment: But i was able to access it. The above code is valid. And i am getting an output 2 as well. I wanted to know how does it have the scope?

Comment: Callname._count return 2

Answer (score 0):

As in example:

```
class decorate_class:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self._func = f
        self._count = 0

    def __call__(self, *args, **kargs):
        self._count += 1
        return self._func(*args, **kargs)

@decorate_class
def callname(name):
   print("Hello, {0}".format(name))


callname('bobo')
callname('dodo')
callname('will return 3')
print('It returns ->> ', callname._count)
```

**result:**

```
Hello, bobo
Hello, dodo
Hello, will return 3
It returns ->>  3
```

**Explanation**

As you decorate your function you basicly each time are calling `decorate_class` by passing you'r function `callname` and the `__call__` method is called when the instance is called and it holds in memory `_count` that you'r `callname` function inherits from `__init__`.

I hope it's clearer now :)

Comment: Does this mean that callname function would inherit any attribute present in the class?

Comment: Basically yes, but if it's a Pythonic way of doing, I can't tell you :)